# For loop parsing a variable from text file

Tags: windows, csv, command-line, cmd, command-prompt

I am running a FOR loop on hundreds of txt files in a directory.  The command run on each file is the same however there Is one variable (number) that is unique for each file.  This variable is in the last column of each row throughout the file (csv) - same number for the whole file. Is there a way to parse this and set it as a variable before running the command?

FOR %%I IN (*)  DO xxx.exe parameters

Alternatively could I make a text file containing all the filenames and the variable for each file and run it that way.

Comment: Is the "last column" always in the same place? Column 7? If so, then this is pretty easy.

Comment: Yes last colum always in the same place,  the variable is the same throughout the file. Therefore only need to read the last value in the first row and then set that as a variable to be part of the command executed on the whole file.

Answer (score 0):

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

FOR %%I IN (*) DO (

   rem Get first row from this file
   set /P "row1=" < "%%I"

   rem Get last column from first row separated by comma or space
   for %%a in (!row1!) do set "number=%%a"

   xxx.exe /file "%%I" /number !number!

)
```

Comment: Aacini's script works if the number is always the last field. If it is not, or if you want to skip setting number for each field in the line, you could use `FOR /F "delims=; tokens=1-4" %%a IN ("!row1!") DO (SET "number=%%d")`

Comment: @Liturgist: Of course that this solution works only when the number is the last field! Didn't you read the OP's request? `"there Is one variable (number) that is unique for each file. This variable is in the last column of each row"`, and `"need to read the last value in the first row and then set that as a variable"`. Are you suggesting that I should post solutions for non-asked questions? **`:/`** (I am afraid I don't understand the purpose of your comment)

Comment: Thank you for your help @Aacini. Can you please explain why the `(set /p "row1=" < "%%I") ` only reads one row from the text file, i though it would type the whole file out? Why do we need to use delayed expansion for this?

Comment: When using the redirection command `<` is there  a way to skip the first line of the file. The first line of the txt file contains header information.

Comment: The `set /P` command reads _one line_; see set help: `set /?` or [this page](http://ss64.com/nt/set.html) for further details. Delayed expansion is needed to process variables that _change its value_ inside a code block, that is, enclosed in parentheses into a `for` or `if` command. Search this site for "delayed expansion" or read the explanation in the same `set /?` help. To read the _second_ line, use: `(set /P "row1=" & set /P "row1=") < "%%I"`

Comment: Worked this solution for you? If so, please select it (check the green mark) and upvote it. Thanks!

Comment: @Aacini - No, I am not suggesting answers for unasked questions. The thing is that sometimes things change. Explicit code is often more maintainable than implicit code.